# How do I obtain an Access-Token for PayPal rest api - Live server

Tags: php, rest, paypal

According to the [PayPal Developer Documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/accept-credit-cards/), when making a REST call, I need to supply the 'Access-Token', which I am unable to locate inside the PayPal control panel in my PayPal account.

```
curl -v https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment \
  -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer Access-Token" \
  -d '{
  "intent": "sale",
  "payer":
  {
    "payment_method": "credit_card",
    "funding_instruments": [
    {
      "credit_card":
      {
        "number": "4012888888881881",
        "type": "mastercard",
        "expire_month": 12,
        "expire_year": 2018,
        "cvv2": 111,
        "first_name": "Betsy",
        "last_name": "Buyer"
      }
    }]
  },
  "transactions": [
  {
    "amount":
    {
      "total": "7.47",
      "currency": "USD"
    },
    "description": "This is the payment transaction description."
  }]
}'
```

How can I obtain the 'Access-Token' for a live (not sandbox) PayPal account ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of googling I came here: [Developer Paypal](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/paypal-here/merchant-onboarding/obtaining-refresh-token-and-access-tokens/)

I hope this helps you.

Comment: This does help. You will likely need to add some information from that page here to keep this answer alive as editors are rather particular about link only solutions. I did find this after :  https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/auth-headers/   which appears to be more specific towards the REST api.

Comment: OP's link is broken.